# Faster way to calculate distance between all individuals during each time step

Tags: r, data.table

I have data on positions of several individuals, each registered at several time steps. I want to calculate distance between each animal to all other animals registered at the same time step.

Here's a simplified example, with data on three individuals ('animal_id') registered on three dates ('date') each, on different positions ('x', 'y'):

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(animal_id = 1, date = as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03")), 
                  x = runif(3, -10, 10), y = runif(3, -10, 10))
dt2 <- data.table(animal_id = 2, date = as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03")), 
                  x = runif(3, -10, 10), y = runif(3, -10, 10))
dt3 <- data.table(animal_id = 3, date = as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03")), 
                  x = runif(3, -10, 10), y = runif(3, -10, 10))
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2, dt3))

# Create dist function between two animals at same time
dist.between.animals <- function(collar_id1, x1, y1, collar_id2, x2, y2) {
  if (collar_id1 == collar_id2) return(NA)
  sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
}

# Get unique collar id of each animal, create column name for all animals per animal
animal_ids <- dt[ , unique(animal_id)]
animal_ids_str <- dt[,paste0("dist_to_", unique(animal_id))]
datetimes <- dt[ , unique(date)]

# Calculate distance of each animal to all animals, at same time
for (i in 1:length(animal_ids)) {
  for (j in 1:length(datetimes)) {
    x1 <- dt[.(animal_ids[i], datetimes[j]), x, on = .(animal_id, date)]
    y1 <- dt[.(animal_ids[i], datetimes[j]), y, on = .(animal_id, date)]
    dt[date == datetimes[j], animal_ids_str[i] := mapply(function(c, x2, y2) dist.between.animals(animal_ids[i], x1, y1, c, x2, y2), animal_id, x, y)]
  }
}
```

Here's an example of what the output should look like:

```
   animal_id       date          x          y dist_to_1  dist_to_2  dist_to_3
1:         1 2014-01-01 -7.0276047  4.7660664        NA  7.1354265 13.7962800
2:         1 2014-01-02 -6.6383802  7.0087919        NA  3.7003879 16.4294999
3:         1 2014-01-03 -0.9722872 -4.8638019        NA 11.6447645 11.8313410
4:         2 2014-01-01  0.1076661  4.8131960  7.135426         NA  7.7052205
5:         2 2014-01-02 -8.9042124  4.0832364  3.700388         NA 13.3225921
6:         2 2014-01-03  8.2858839  2.1992575 11.644764         NA  0.4569632
7:         3 2014-01-01  5.7519522 -0.4320359 13.796280  7.7052205         NA
8:         3 2014-01-02 -9.0805265 -9.2381889 16.429500 13.3225921         NA
9:         3 2014-01-03  8.6832729  1.9736531 11.831341  0.4569632         NA
```

However, my real data have about 30 animals with 20,000 observations per animal, so my current code takes a long time to run. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you always have one position per date per animal, and the same dates for all animals?

Comment: Not all animals were collared on same dates or their GPS positions were sampled at same frequency, so the distance value should be left NA if there is no known GPS position from either one of two animals at same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a self-join on date (`dt[dt, on = "date",`), and for each match (`by = .EACHI`) calculate the distance:

```
dt[dt, on = "date",
   .(from_id = id, to_id = i.id, dist = sqrt((x - i.x)^2 + (y - i.y)^2)), by = .EACHI]
```

---

I you wish to turn the data to a wide format (`dcast`), chain this to the code above:

```
[ , dcast(.SD, from_id + date ~ to_id, value.var = "dist")]
```

---

It seems to perform OK in a benchmark using the data of @digEmAll

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  digemall = dt[,(animal_ids_str):=distancesInSameDate(.SD,animal_ids_str),by=date],
  henrik =   dt[dt, on = "date",
                .(from_id = animal_id, to_id = i.animal_id, dist = sqrt((x - i.x)^2 + (y - i.y)^2)), by = .EACHI][
                  , dcast(.SD, from_id + date ~ to_id, value.var = "dist")],
  times = 5, unit = "relative")

# Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# digemall 3.206063 2.058547 2.189487 2.035975 2.032324 2.019082     5
#   henrik 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000     5
```

---

Note that I haven't renamed the "to_id" in my code. That basically reflects my prefence to keep the data in long format, and in that format I would like to have both the 'from_id' and 'to_id' without any prefix. If you want prefix in the columns in the wide format, just add `to_id = paste0("dist_to_", i.animal_id)` in the first step.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so here's kind of an unorthodox method, especially given that for once I think datatables make the situation worse. I'm using the `dist` function, which calculates the Euclidean distance (or any other, your pick). If you use `diag=T, upper=T`it generates a matrix that you can then assign to the specified rows-columns. Creating the columns might get tedious with multiple animals, but nothing that the `paste` function can't fix.

```
dt[, c("dist_to_1", "dist_to_2", "dist_to_3") := NA]
dt<- arrange(dt, date, animal_id) # order by date. here it turns into a data.frame

for (i in 1:length(unique(dt$date))){
    sub<- subset(dt, dt$date == unique(dt$date)[i])
    dt[which(dt$date == unique(sub$date)), c("dist_to_1", "dist_to_2", "dist_to_3")]<- as.matrix(dist(sub[, c("x","y")], diag=T, upper=T))
}

dt[dt==0]<- NA #assign NAs for 0s. Not necessary if the it's ok for diag==0.
setDT(dt) # back to datatable. Again this part is not really necessary.
dt<- dt[order(animal_id, date)] # order as initially ordered
```

Using this code:

```
> proc.time()-ptm
   user  system elapsed 
  0.051   0.007   0.068
```

Using earlier code:

```
> proc.time()-ptm
   user  system elapsed 
  0.083   0.004   0.092
```

If you find a way to use both `dist` and `data.table` you're golden, but I couldn't figure it out. It's pretty fast, since it calls C, and it will get faster the more observations you add.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach which should be much faster :

```
library(data.table)

### CREATE A BIG DATASET
set.seed(123)
nSamples <- 20000
nAnimals <- 30
allDates <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-01")) + (1:nSamples)*24*3600
dts <- lapply(1:nAnimals, function(id){
                            data.table(animal_id=id,date=allDates,
                                       x=runif(nSamples,-10,10), y=runif(nSamples,-10,10))
              })
dt <- rbindlist(dts)

### ALTERNATIVE APPROACH (NO LOOP)
animal_ids_str <- dt[,paste0("dist_to_",sort(unique(animal_id)))]
# set keys
setkey(dt,animal_id,date)
# add the distance columns
dt[,(animal_ids_str):=as.double(NA)]

# custom function that computes animal distances for a subset of dt at the same date
distancesInSameDate <- function(subsetDT,animal_ids_str){
  m <- as.matrix(dist(subsetDT[,.(x,y)]))
  diag(m) <- NA
  cols <- paste0("dist_to_",subsetDT$animal_id)
  missingCols <- animal_ids_str[is.na(match(animal_ids_str,cols))]
  m <- cbind(m,matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(m),ncol=length(missingCols)))
  colnames(m) <- c(cols,missingCols)
  DF <- as.data.frame(m,stringsAsFactors=F)
  DF <- DF[,match(animal_ids_str,colnames(DF))]
  return(DF)
}
# let's compute the distances
system.time( dt[,(animal_ids_str):=distancesInSameDate(.SD,animal_ids_str),by=date] )
```

On my machine it takes :

```
   user  system elapsed 
  13.76    0.00   13.82
```